# Twilio Test Credentials phone number not verified

Tags: twilio

I am busy writing integration tests for Twilio outbound calls.
Code has been written and all works fine, but want to ensure code coverage with tests.

Using Test Credentials provided and phone number: **+15005550006** for the from number,

I get the following error: **"Unable to create record: The source phone number provided, +15005550006, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio."**

I have verified that I am using the test credentials to make the API call.

Answer (score 1):

I was no able to reproduce the issue. Are you using a non-trial account? If you are, my recommendation would be to open a ticket at help@twilio.com for further investigation of the issue, along with the full details to reproduce the issue.

[How To Use Twilio Test Credentials with Magic Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/04/twilio-test-credentials-magic-numbers.html)